# How can I implement the moving line on a graph like that in the native "data usage" app of android

Tags: android, android-layout, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm using mpandroidchart's bar chart and I need to implement a horizontal moving line on top of this chart. I also want the upper part of this chart to change the color as I move this line up or down.

Is there provision to implement this already or will I have to write my own code? Or will it be easier to get some part of the library tweaked?

Thanks in advance.